# How to only print a string that starts with 'M' in PHP?

Tags: php, substring

So I'm trying to print only the names of the months that start with the letter 'M' but I can't seem to figure out the specific substring code that will get me there. This is all I have and I'm not sure if I even need it?

```
foreach ($month as $x) {
print($x);
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: post the code what you have tried. We can't help you to build entire logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use php substr to check the first letter of string if starts with letter 'M'. see code below

```
foreach($month as $x) {
   if (strtolower(substr($x, 0, 1))  == 'm') {
     print($x);
   }
}
```

Or, directly access its index, like.

```
foreach($month as $x) {
    if (strtolower($x[0]))  == 'm') {
       print($x);
    }
}
```

see docs here [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: Oh okay, that makes sense! Thank you!